# Using Firestore with Flask/Jinja, correct method to query and display results to DOM

Tags: flask, google-cloud-firestore, jinja2

```
@app.route('/view_case/<case_name>')
def view_case(case_name):
    query = db.collection('cases').document(case_name).collection('documents').get()

    documents = []
    for _document in query:
        documents.append(_document)

    return render_template('views/view_case.html', documents=documents)
```

Is the above method the correct way to query a group of documents and send them to the DOM as a list to be iterated over by jinja to display?

Side question, I notice the results dont include the documents ID, is there a way to attach the id to the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just amended to use list comprehension

```
from google.cloud import firestore

db = firestore.Client()

collection_ref = db.collection(u'collection').get()
documents = list(doc.to_dict() for doc in collection_ref)
```